# How create a .conf file in a openvpn for run automatically on system startup?

Tags: openvpn

I want run OpenVPN automatically on system startup. But How can I create a .conf file for my server after using scp in my client desktop?

What do I have to put inside of this .conf file? [In a HOWTO in openvpn nothing is written](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#startup)?

Comment: Can you try and expand this a bit? I don't fully understand what you mean by the `scp` comment? Also have you consulted the OpenVPN Howto on the project's website? http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question as 'I am remotely configuring my server to which I am logged in using scp', then here are a few guidelines on how to set up openvpn on that server (and your client):

To start the OpenVPN listening service automatically on the server make sure you have a valid .conf file in the /etc/openvpn/ directory. When the openvpn service starts it will automatically try to run any network configurations found in the aforementioned directory. This will set up the listening part for the openvpn service.

On the client you will also need the openvpn service, but with a slightly different .conf file. When the openvpn service starts on the client you can have it automatically connect to the server at boot up using the same technique of placing the .conf file in /etc/openvpn/. The website slm refers to is by far the best resource available for setting up openvpn.

My advice is to start with the very basic setup using a static key and get that working first. Look for the 'Static Key Mini-HOWTO' on how to accomplish this.